# Geofence and OneSignal together Crash ionic3 app

Tags: ionic3, onesignal, geofencing, ionic-native

**Geofence and OneSignal these two plugins not working with together.**

the main issue is after plugins installation my app is installed successfully on device (tested on android) but when click to the open app that time app is crash (not open).
after then i have checked with only one plugin at a time then its working fine.

Please help me,

thanks

**Steps i have foloowed**

1 - Create new application.
2 - install plugins

```
 - Geofence
        $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence
        $ npm install --save @ionic-native/geofence

 - OneSignal
       $ ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
       $ npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

3 - run app on device (without doing any changes)

```
 - Ionic cordova run android
```

**Ionic Info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 6.1.2 
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Volumes/TimeMachine/Android_SDK
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: did you check console logs? are you getting anything?

Comment: Faced Same issue @Spanchal.
I had installed same plugins in my project. but met with the same issue.

Comment: hello @SurajRao, yes i have checked, there is no error in console. and please follow my steps and check in your project. you will get to know.

Comment: just to be clear... you did [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) right? not terminal

Comment: yes, @SurajRao i have check remote debugging its showing nothing and app crashed.

Comment: am not entirely sure.. is there a reason you are using older version cordova and android sdk?

Comment: @SurajRao please you can tried it for once you will get it the exact issue what i am trying to saying.

Comment: can you add the code where you are using both?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening since the following error occurs, because of a dependency conflict between OneSignal and the Geofence plugins.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
```

But if you modify the Geofence plugin either by changing the local pull you have or creating a branch of the project and pull from that, you can get OneSignal and the Geofence Cordova plugins working together.

The line you need to comment out is line 49 of plugins -> cordova-plugin-geofence -> plugin.xml

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+" />
```

One you do that you will need to remove and add android as a platform again

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```